# get last clicked tab index in jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery UI tabs , to get the current selected tab i am using ui.index but i want an 
index of last clicked tab.

for example,
initially tab 1 is loaded 
after that if i click tab 3 then in show method i can fetch tab 1's index 
and the same way if i click on tab 1 then i can fetch tab 3's index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set a prevTab variable that is accessed during the show method and then reset to be the current tab?

```
var prevTab = 0;
$('#tabs').tabs({
   show: function(event, ui) {
       alert(prevTab);  //do something with previous tab index
       prevTab = ui.index;  //set the new previous tab index to the current index
   }
});
```

You could also set a cookie with the previous tab index.

Comment: in my case, ui.index is always undefined. Do you why? Thanks